# Rename() not working

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

Why does the rename function not work?

```
$new_image_name = $maximum_id + 1 . '.jpg';
$old_image_name = $file_name;

// Rename the image file
rename($profile_folder . $old_image_name, $profile_folder . $new_image_name);
```

```
var_dump($profile_folder . $old_image_name, $profile_folder . $new_image_name);
```

gives me
 `string(56) "/var/www/myproject/public/images/1/profile/old.jpg" string(50) "/var/www/myproject/public/images/1/profile/1.jpg"`

```
var_dump(rename($profile_folder . $old_image_name, $profile_folder . $new_image_name));
```

returns `(bool)false`

The paths are correct, however the file is not renamed and uploaded with the old name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions. Try to set up at 0777 just for testing.

Comment: Good idea! I did this `chmod($profile_folder, 0777);` that did not solve the problem.

Comment: It might seem problem in uploading and renaming code order. Upload file first and then rename it.

Comment: Very good idea. I even tried to call the rename function manually, long after the file was uploaded and that does not work. So there has to be something wrong with how I use the function.